# Turning frequency dictionary into frequency matrix

Tags: python

I would like to turn a frequency dictionary into a frequency matrix.
I have the following code:

```
words = {
  "file1.txt" : tf2[0],
  "file2.txt" : tf2[1],
  "file3.txt" : tf2[2],
}



matrix = []
for line in words:
   line = line.strip("\n")
   a = line.split(";")
   for i in range(len(a)):
      try:
        a[i] = float(a[i])
      except ValueError:
        pass
        matrix.append(a)
print(matrix)
```

The for line part doesn't seem to take the tf2[0] etc as part of the dictionary. I wouldn't know how to fix this.
The words dic currently prints :

```
{'file1.txt': {'eye': 1, 'head': 1, 'leg': 1}, 'file2.txt': {'eye': 1, 'head': 1}, 'file3.txt': {'eye': 1, 'leg': 2, 'foot':1}}
```

I want it to become something like this (preferably in floats) :

```
[['', 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'],
['leg', 1, 0, 2],
['eye', 1, 1, 1],
['head', 1, 1, 0],
['foot', 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first convert the dictionary to a dataframe

```
d = {'file1.txt': {'eye': 1, 'head': 1, 'leg': 1}, 'file2.txt': {'eye': 1, 'head': 1}, 'file3.txt': {'eye': 1, 'leg': 2, 'foot':1}}
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df
```

this produces almost what you want:

```
            file1.txt   file2.txt   file3.txt
eye         1.0         1.0         1.0
head        1.0         1.0         NaN
leg         1.0         NaN         2.0
foot        NaN         NaN         1.0
```

then we extract all the data as a double list -- the main point here being that we want the index and column names in it as well hence `reset_index` stuff together with transposing `T`, and replacing NaNs with 0s

```
(df.fillna(0)
   .astype(int)
   .rename_axis('')
   .reset_index()
   .T
   .reset_index()
   .T
   .values.tolist()
)
```

produces

```
[['', 'file1.txt', 'file2.txt', 'file3.txt'],
 ['eye', 1, 1, 1],
 ['head', 1, 1, 0],
 ['leg', 1, 0, 2],
 ['foot', 0, 0, 1]]
```